# What is the motivation to introduce Tate-cohomology groups?

Tags: number-theory, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology, motivation, galois-cohomology

What is the motivation to introduce Tate-cohomology groups ?

Let $G$ be a Galois group and $M$ be a $G-$module.
Let $H^n(G,M)$ be usual Galois cohomology.

In group cohomology theory, we often introduce Tate-cohomology $\hat{H^n}(G,M)$in the area of number theory.

For $n\ge 1$, notion of usual Galois cohomology and Tate-cohomology coincides, but when $n=0$, it does not.

What is the motivation to introduce the notion, Tate-cohomology ?

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tate_cohomology_group). The motivation for Tate was Tate's Theorem, that the cup product gives an isomorphism then (I suppose).